# Windows phone 8.1 assets

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, assets, windows-store

I'm developing an WP8.1 application and now when I'm almost done with it, I tried to run the Windows App Certification Kit to test if everything is ok. I got this error: [image: App manifest resources test]

I know that this is not a big thing (it should be really easy to fix it) but I would like to make the images to be as great a possible. I have found the default sampled in the Assets folder, but I don't really know how they should look like at the end.

Could someone provide me with some samples (perhaps some samples he used) for the following images:

```
ApplicationIcon.png
BadgeLogo.png
Logo.png
SplashScreen.png
SquareTile71x71.png
SquareTile150x150.png
StoreLogo.png
WideLogo.png
```

And the ones in the Tiles folder that is also inside the Assets folder:

```
FlipCycleTileLarge.png
FlipCycleTileMedium.png
FlipCycleTileSmall.png
IconicTileMediumLarge.png
IconicTileSmall.png
```

PS
I'll make my own pictures (I can post them later if you would like that) But I would just like to see some examples to know how that should look like.

Comment: This question is not about programming at all. Maybe you'd be better off at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: thx, i know that it is not about programming but i didn't know where to ask :)
i'll ask it there now

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphic design, rather than programming.

Comment: The problem is, we programmer face this problem more often than graphicdesigners. I just converted a working wp8.0-app to wp8.1 and got those defualt images. So I'd like to know what to do with them. My graphic designer most likely will just know about it when I tell, that I need the app logo in some sizes. But only I know where it comes from. So I'd say this still has to do with the project/solution and is a programmer-question. He/she didn't ask for how to design or make it look fancy ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The image requirements are relatively simple;

There are 7 images that you can specify in the appxmanifest, and can refer to any image within the project (so the exact filenames aren't strictly *required*, although I would stick with them). Each image can be supplied at three scales, and if you only supply one scale, make it the 240% scale for the best impression on higher resolution devices.

The Square 71x71 Logo, Square 150x150 Logo, Wide 310 x 150 Logo are all used for tile images, when your app is pinned, and would normally contain some kind of logo to represent your app, on a transparent background where it makes sense.

The Square 44x44 Logo is used in the app list, and is generally a scaled version of the tile image, also on a transparent background.

The Store Logo is as used in the store, and again is generally a scaled version of the tile image.

The Badge Logo is used for lockscreen notifications, and only need be specified if your app supports lockscreen notifications. It also **must** only be white on transparent.

The Splash Screen is shown as your app is loading. Some apps choose to just show a larger version of the logo on a brand colour (e.g. Internet Explorer), others show some form of branding, along with a "loading" type of message.

Microsoft do also publish some guidelines for design, available from the [dev centre](https://dev.windows.com/en-gb/design/assets)

Comment: iImage Sizes 
360 x 360    Logo.scale-240
106x106      SmallLogo.scale-240
1152x1920    SplashScreen.scale-240
170x170      Square71x71Logo.scale-240
120x120      StoreLogo.scale-240
744 x 360    WideLogo.scale-240